# AWS XML response error signature does not match

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2

I have a bash script that should return the XML response for AWS EC2 regions
but I am getting an XML error response as:

> "SignatureDoesNotMatch" The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Is the method for generating the signature for EC2 web query correct? Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date +%FT%TZ | sed 's/:/%3A/g')
echo "$dt"

q="GET
ec2.amazonaws.com
/
Action=DescribeRegions&AWSAccessKeyId=<aws access key>&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=$dt&Version=2013-02-01"

sig=$(echo -en "$q" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "<aws secret key>" -binary | openssl enc -base64)
echo "the signature is $sig"

curl --get --data-urlencode DATA "https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions&AWSAccessKeyId=<aws access key>&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=$dt&Version=2013-02-01&Signature=$sig"
echo -e "\n\n finished "
```

P.S: the AWS access key and AWS secret key are removed for security reason, they work very well.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `?` after the `/` in the definition of `q`. Is that a typo in the question or the solution to your problem?

Comment: @rici that is not typo its the way any aws web request  query to signed accord to aws ,see this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the post contains the real code, then the problem is probably the `--data-urlencode DATA` in the curl request. That will cause `&DATA` to be appended to the request, which is certainly not what you want. I believe that you need to url encode the signature ("The resulting signature must be base-64 encoded and then URI encoded.") which you can do with:

```
curl --get --data-urlencode "Signature=$sig" "https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions&AWSAccessKeyId=<aws access key>&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=$dt&Version=2013-02-01"
```

I'd suggest using the `-v` command-line option to `curl` for debugging purposes; it will let you see the actual request line, which you can then compare with the expected format.

Also, make sure there are no trailing spaces in the definition of `q`.

As a side-issue, there is no reason to specify the `-e` flag to `echo`. `-e` is used to cause `\`-sequences such as `\n` to be changed to the actual characters (hex `0A` in this case); you don't have any `\` in `$q`, so there is no need to recode. `-e` is *not* necessary to cause actual newlines in the argument to be echoed.